# How to match two CSS class attribute values via XPath?

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath

I looked at the answers for the questions on how to select elements with more than one class. One of the solutions is:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]
```

But this would break with if a `div` element had a class string containing `class1` or `class2`. Is there an official way for selecting tags with more than one class? Will this way break?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that your XPath could match undesired `@class` values:

> ```
> //div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]
> ```
>
> But this would break with if a tag had a class string containing
>   class1 or class2

For example, the above XPath will match `div` elements with any of the following `@class` attribute values:

```
class="class10 class20"
class="notclass1 notclass2"
class="class1class2"
```

The usual safeguard is to prepend and append spaces to `@class` as well as to the targeted string:

```
//div[    contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' class1 ')
      and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' class2 ')]
```

This improved XPath will not match such undesired variations as mentioned above.